# Regex to parse out filename and partial path, conditionally

Tags: c#, regex, search, .net-2.0

I have a C# app that uses the search functions to find all files in a directory, then shows them in a list. I need to be able to filter the files based on extension (possible using the search function) *and* directory (eg, block any in the "test" or "debug" directories from showing up).

My current code is something like:

```
Regex filter = new Regex(@"^docs\(?!debug\)(?'display'.*)\.(txt|rtf)");
String[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles("docs\\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach ( String file in filelist )
{
    Match m = filter.Match(file);
    if ( m.Success )
    {
        listControl.Items.Add(m.Groups["display"]);
    }
}
```

(that's somewhat simplified and consolidated, the actual regex is created from a string read from a file and I do more error checking in between.)

I need to be able to pick out a section (usually a relative path and filename) to be used as the display name, while ignoring any files with a particular foldername as a section of their path. For example, for these files, only ones with +s should match:

```
+ docs\info.txt
- docs\data.dat
- docs\debug\info.txt
+ docs\world\info.txt
+ docs\world\pictures.rtf
- docs\world\debug\symbols.rtf
```

My regex works for most of those, except I'm not sure how to make it fail on the last file. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: There still appear to be typos in your regex: You need to escape the backslashes (`\\`) or else they will escape your lookahead's parentheses into literal parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^docs\\(?:(?!\bdebug\\).)*\.(?:txt|rtf)$
```

will match a string that

1. starts with `docs\`,
2. does not contain `debug\` anywhere (the `\b` anchor ensures that we match `debug` as an entire word), and
3. ends with `.txt` or `.rtf`.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx).  This should do what you want.

Example:

```
// Only get files that end in ".txt"
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Console.WriteLine("The number of files ending with .txt is {0}.", dirs.Length);
foreach (string dir in dirs) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

Comment: That's the function I'm using, actually (typo in the code example). My problem is it won't filter out files that are in a "bad" subdirectory within that directory. I also need to keep the filter in a file (though that can be done with GetFiles too).